# Ryzen Install 20.10 fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a Ryzen 5, 4700 and just tried to install 20.10 to a fresh Partition using "Something else" and when it boots, it goes to BusyBox and I have no idea where to go from there. The "Try Ubuntu" worked perfectly when I was installing. Loved it.

I tried "Continue" and "Ctrl+D" as suggested but it just hangs.

I tried turning UEFI On/Off same thing.

Is there something else I need to do? Ubuntu 20.01 and 20.04 both previously installed without issue but I would like the later kernel of 20.10.

How do I make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Install 20.04, the 5.8 will come in a week or two with HWE. It is in `proposed` already.

Comment: What do you mean you installed to a "fresh partition"? Did you create some partition(s) and file system(s) ahead of time?  The installer will work better if you give it *unpartitioned free space*.  For example, if you try to install Ubuntu to a NTFS partition (or really any file system created in Windows), then Ubuntu might not be able to use the volume properly.  If you don't plan to install another operating system, use the "Disks" app in the live session to format (erase) the entire disk (as GPT) and then begin the installation process.

Comment: @Pilot6 You can even install 5.8 now with the package `linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`.

Comment: @Pilot6: Thanks, I am already running that with my own install of Kernel 5.8.14. It is not maintained by Ubuntu so I have to keep checking for Kernel updates and manually update them with the .deb files. Getting lazy :) Got excited when I read that 20.10 had 5.8 instead of the old 5.4.52.

Comment: @red_trumpet: How do I do that? Where/how do I use that command?

Comment: @user2445336 Type `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` in your terminal. Should do the trick

Comment: @red_trumpet: Thanks I will give that a try.